# C Stack Error Linked LIst

Tags: c

There are huge amounts of error, Seriously what's wrong ?
I tried using it wihout typedef but what's the problem? can anyone help me debug this please?

```
struct node {
    int info;
    struct node *link;
};

int main (void)
{
    int choice;
    struct node *top;
    top = NULL;
    while (1) {
        printf("1.Push\n");
        printf("2.Pop\n");
        printf("3.Display\n");
        printf("4.Quit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                push();
                break;
            case 2:
                pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                display();
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(1);
            default:
                printf("Wrong choice\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void push (void)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    int pushed_item;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    printf("Input the new value to be pushed on the stack : ");
    scanf("%d", &pushed_item);
    tmp->info = pushed_item;
    tmp->link = top;
    top = tmp;
}

void pop (void)
{
    struct node *tmp;
    if (top == NULL)
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    else {
        tmp = top;
        printf("Popped item is %d\n", tmp->info);
        top = top->link;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

void display (void)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr = top;
    if (top == NULL)
     printf("Stack is empty\n");
    else {
        printf("Stack elements :\n");
        while (ptr != NULL) {
            printf("%d\n", ptr->info);
            ptr = ptr->link;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly, please?

Comment: And what are the errors you're getting?  Please post the precise error messages.

Comment: Please post the compiler you are using, the compiler options you are using, and the specific error output that you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `main` function is going to have to be below the functions it calls.  Secondly, you need to `#import <stdio.h>` to use `printf`.  Thirdly, `top` is not a global variable so you can't just use it inside the `display` function.

Work from there.

Comment: `#import` or `#include` - too much Java there buddy!

Comment: Also, if his code is structured correctly, his functions are in a `.h` file, and this is just his code file. (Note, that's an if. And by the looks of the code, a big if.)

Comment: The `main` function does not have to be below the functions it calls - just prototype the other functions up above (should be in a header file generally).

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this snippet at the top of your file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void push(void);
void pop(void);
void display(void);

struct node* top; // good catch by Borealid
```

Comment: You will also need #include<stdlib.h> for the exit and free.